# Creating a program for Volunteers, how should I store the data?(xml, sql, etc)

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, storage

Disclaimer: Yes, I am fairly new to storing data in files. But this is something I'm willing to learn, and take the time to learn

I am working on creating a program for someone who keeps track of volunteers and how much time they spend working, and what they are working on.

For each volunteer I will have their Address Information, email, phone, etc. I will also have what show they worked, how long they worked it for, and what position they were working.

Later, the user will be able to access a way to print out monthly reports of this information.

I am wondering if anyone is willing to give me a nudge in the right direction. How should I store all this data? I've heard of XML, SQL, JSON, and other things here and there. I need something that can handle large amounts of data, as there are about 200 volunteers right now, and data will need to be constantly added to this file(s). Are there any suggestions? If you need me to clarify something, please just ask.

Also, I am using Windows Forms Application, C#.

Comment: Okay, I apologize for being too general. I did some looking around on many options, and there is just so much out there. I was just looking for some guidance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are different ways to accomplish this, most preferred ones would be either SQL database (MySQL, MSSQL, SQLite, etc.), JSON storage (and GZipping, for good measures. Saving storage, you know), or binary storage (aka. knowing the complete size of the data you're storing, such as how many Int32's, and reading this in bytes from a file).

I'd go with the JSON storage if you're not planning on accessing this data from more than 1 computer.

If portability is what you want, you're gonna want to go with SQL.

If you're just looking for a simple way to store data, then it'd be either JSON or binary saving.

These are probably the best choices you have, on how to save data.

@Edit: Seeing how you've specified large amounts of data, your best shot would be either SQL or Binary. Binary, because you can jump around in files because you know the size of each object, so you wont have to read all of them. SQL because it has this feature built as part of the core. Json simply wont be a very good choice for large amounts of data.

XML, you're gonna want to avoid entirely, unless you want to be able to export data because other applications requires it in XML format. XML simply uses too large amounts of storage space, due to the whole structure of the language.

@Edit2: Would whoever downvoted my answer, explain why please? .__.'

Comment: I appreciate your response very much. SQL sounds like the way for me to go. But one question on that. You said XML is good for exporting data. How about SQL? This data will need to be able to be sent to Word or Excel or something, so that it can be printed out and viewed in a table-like format. Can I do that with SQL?

Comment: I do believe programs like Excel has native support for XML importing, while not for SQL. However writing a converter between you SQL structure to XML isn't difficult at all. @Edit, whoever down voted, please state why.

Answer (score -1):

SQL can handle pretty much a lot of data. It is easy to use for a beginner and there is a lot of support for it.

Comment: Whoever downvoted this should leave a comment explaining why.

Comment: @nhgrif No, I'm not obligated to do that but now that I'm here anyway: The question is asking for opinions (which is off-topic and might be better suited for progammers.se if the question had more focus). Given the broad and opninion based nature of the question this answer is maybe a start of an answer but I can't imagine it being useful for anyone, maybe it is for the OP. For me that makes the answer not useful (and that is what the downvote expresses).